# How to define a iterative function involving for loop where the iterator i,j,l.. are also used in the defined iterative function

Tags: python, list, function, loops, iterator

I'm trying to use a recursive function to simplify below 'for-loops' for any number of loops that I may have to run the program based on the requirement. I can define a recursive function without the use of i, j, k, l.... in the function but I have no idea or I'm having difficulty in defining a iterative function with the use of i,j k...
I would be glad if someone could aid my imagination a little bit on it.

```
adjcent_spin_product_matrix = []
z_partial = 0
spin = [-1, 1]
for i in spin:
    for j in spin:
        for k in spin:
            for l in spin:
               for m in spin:
                   for o in spin:
                       for p in spin:
                           adjcent_spin_product_matrix = adjcent_spin_product_matrix + [i*j+ j*k+ k*l+ l*n+ m*o+ o*p]
```

Comment: I really don't understand this. For one thing, `spin` is a list of only 2 elements, so referring to `spin[3]` etc. will crash your script with an error. And despite all those loops defining loop variables `i` up to `p`, you're only ever using `i`, `j` and `k`. No-one's going to be able to help you simplify this code if you can't provide a working version, or we can't understand what it is you're trying to do.

Comment: But now that makes even less sense. Why are you iterating over the same values so many times?

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve asks to get a matrix of adjacent spin products and the final function needs to use the i, j, k... to describe the matrix. so, for each spin pair[-1, 1] there is one for-loop and the number of for loops depends on the number of lattice points.

Comment: Its just spin, not spin[3] etc.. I re-edited the code. Basically, I want to condense all the for-loops to a recursive function and I would also like to use the i, j, k.... from each for-loop in writing final function. So, I want you to understand that i, j, k, l...... play part in the code.

Comment: As others have remarked your question is not the clearest ever posed... I have posted an answer and I'm confident that its current version is to the point, but not 100% (nor 95% ;-) sure that it's exactly what you've asked for.  Could you please tell me, is it OK or I'd better remove it? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No particular need for a recursive function.

You can use *a single loop* for every number of indices if you use `itertools.product`; you can simplify the computation too, using `sum` and `zip`

```
from itertools import product
...
spin_products = []
n = int(input('how many indices? '))
...
for indices in product([-1, 1], repeat=n):
    spin_products.append(sum(i*j for i, j in zip(indices, indices[1:])))
```

Comment: Of course loops containing `list.append(...)` can usually be changed to a list comprehension and this is no exception, `... = [sum(i*j for i, j in zip(ix, ix[1:])) for ix in product((-1,1), repeat=n)]`

Comment: zip(indices, indices[1:]) : That's very clever logic!!

Comment: How did you come up with that? If you may walk me through your thought process in arriving at that logic because for me it wasn't immediately obvious I had to write everything down and look at the pattern to come to a realization that that can be done.

Comment: Pattern recognition maybe? ① any nested loops with code only in the deepest level is a pattern that suggests `itertools.product` - your case was particularly simple because the same iterable was repeated n-times - and ②  the actual computation is a sum of products of pairs, hence `sum` and `zip` that's the Python's way to create pairs of values.

Comment: And, `zip(a_list, a_list[1:]) ` is THE idiom to get consecutive pairs from a list.

Comment: btw, one quick question. what does the for-loop in the above with print(indices) under it return? Is it a tuple or just a stream of numbers? When I run it the output looks like its a stream of tuples of size n  but zip(indices, indices[1:]) suggest that it could be just a stream of numbers all the way n*2**n of them. I hope my question is clear enough to make sense!!

Comment: I went through the code again in detail. I understand It's a tuple!! It's all clear.

Answer (score 2):

My earlier answer was against your unedited post, so here's an update:

From the code you've provided, it's clear that you *must* have at least the loops for `i`, and `j`.

Evaluating that loop on it's own gives the following list:
`[1, -1, -1, 1]`

Now, each subsequent nested loop in your coded merely duplicates each element in this list, and then adds the array (repeated twice) from the previous loop:

The i, j, and k loops give `[1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1] + [1, -1, -1,
 1, 1, -1, -1, 1] = [2, 0, -2, 0, 0, -2, 0, 2]`

The i, j, k, and l loops give `[1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1] + [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1] + [1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1] = [3, 1, -1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3]`

And so on...

Therefore, you could simply try something like the following:

```
adjacent_spin_product_matrix = []
ij_result = [1, -1, -1, 1]

def calc_product(adjacent_spin_product_matrix, number_of_indices):
    if number_of_indices == 2:
        return ij_result
    else:
        number_of_duplicates = 2 ** (number_of_indices - 2)
        curr_array = []
        for elem in ij_result:
            for dup in range(number_of_duplicates):
                curr_array.append(elem)
        prev_array = calc_product(adjacent_spin_product_matrix, number_of_indices - 1)
        temp_array = []
        temp_array.extend(prev_array)
        temp_array.extend(prev_array)
        result = []
        for i, elem in enumerate(curr_array):
            result.append(elem + temp_array[i])

        return result
```

Now, you should find that:

```
print(calc_product([], 2))  # equivalent to i and j case
print(calc_product([], 3))  # equivalent to i, j, and k case
print(calc_product([], 4))  # equivalent to i, j, k, and l case
print(calc_product([], 5))  # equivalent to i, j, k, l, and m case
print(calc_product([], 6))  # equivalent to i, j, k, l, m, and o case
print(calc_product([], 7))  # equivalent to i, j, k, l, m, o, and p case
```

These give the expected results:

```
[1, -1, -1, 1]
[2, 0, -2, 0, 0, -2, 0, 2]
[3, 1, -1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3]
[4, 2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 2, 0, -2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4]
[5, 3, 1, 3, 1, -1, 1, 3, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 1, -1, -3, -1, -3, -5, -3, -1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3, 3, 1, -1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, -1, -3, -5, -3, -1, -3, -1, 1, 3, 1, -1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, 3, 1, -1, 1, 3, 1, 3, 5]
[6, 4, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, -2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, -2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, -2, -4, -6, -4, -2, -4, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, -4, -2, -4, -6, -4, -2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 0, -2, -4, -2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 0, -2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 0, 2, 4, 2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: "Now, each subsequent nested loop in your coded merely duplicates each element in this list, and then adds the array (repeated twice) from the previous loop" can you elaborate more on this statement? what do you mean adds the array repeated twice from previous loop?

Comment: Certainly.  If you look at the output from the iteration with only 2 elements (i and j), it is [1, -1, -1,1]  I create the output for the 3-element iteration as follows: 1) create an array by duplicating every element from the previous (2-element) array.  This gives me [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1].  2) create another temporary array by concatenating the previous (2-element) array to itself.  This produces [1, -1, -1, 1] + [1, -1, -1, 1] = [1, -1, -1, 1, 1, -1, -1, 1]  3) Add the temporary arrays from steps 1 and 2 together to get [2, 0, -2, 0, 0, -2, 0, 2].

Comment: The above can be repeated when creating the 4-element array: 1) Take [1, -1, -1, 1], and repeat every element 4 times: [1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1]  2) Take  [1, -1, -1, 1] and repeat every element twice:  [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1]  3) Concatenate the array from step 2 to itself:  [1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1, 1, 1, -1, -1, -1, -1, 1, 1].  4) Concatenate [1, -1, -1,1] to itself 4 times: [1, -1, -1,1, 1, -1, -1,1, 1, -1, -1,1, 1, -1, -1,1]  5) Add the arrays from 1, 3, and 4: [3, 1, -1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, 1, -1, -3, -1, 1, -1, 1, 3]

Comment: The pattern just repeats for each subsequent iteration.  I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use a recursive function to do this, what you can do is use a [stack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_(abstract_data_type)). Push each level of your loop to the stack, so you can pop them later on.

A stack is a fundamental data structure in most languages as it's a very natural way to store function call contexts, it's also where Stack Overflow got its name from.